# Data validation excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

In data validation, it is possible for a cell to gray out when you made a selection on the cell above it? Example column A1:A3 list drop down are fruit, vegetable, and meat products. If I select vegetable on A1, can A2: A3 automatically gets grayed out? If this is possible, how do I do it? If not, what are my alternative? I will appreciate your help.
Thank you

Comment: Use the `FormulaIs` option in conditional formatting with something like `=LEN(A1)<>0`

Comment: Welcome to Super User. A common mistake new users make is to leave out the details of what they have already attempted before posting their question. There is a reasonable expectation here that you have tried something and are not expecting us to provide a complete solution for you. Please [edit] your question with those details. We will attempt to help you where you are at.

Answer (score 0):

As Gary's Student pointed out, you can use Conditional Formatting to vary the color (set to grey) based on the value of this (or any cell(s)). However, if you are using a Protected sheet and want to enable/disable cells (i.e., set Protection on or off), and also to vary the color of the cell(s) based on whether protected, you'll need to use a bit of VBA to protect/unprotect cells, and then use Conditional formatting to set the color.

The Conditional formatting will set color based on whether the cell is protected. So something like this formula:

> =CELL("protect",$A1)=1

And the VBA could be placed inthe **Worksheet_Change**() sub. You could do this more elegantly, but essentially something like this:

```
If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
   ActiveSheet.Unprotect
   Range("A3").Select
   Selection.Locked = IIf(Range("A2").Value > "", True, False)
   Range("A2").Select
   ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End If
```